# Change application icon after app launched

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Is there any way to change the icon of an application after it is launched? I want to change the icon to reflect a notification.

Thank you

edit:
Wpf solution based on Fredrik Mörks answer.

```
Uri iconUri = new Uri("icon1.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the icon of the main form:

```
this.Icon = new Icon(@"<path to icon on disk");
```

Comment: Thank you Fredrik, that is it. Forgot to mention that it was a WPF app, had to do a little change to work.